# Why is my code displaying NaN instead of an integer when attempting to display a Math.random value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, nan, attr

I am attempting to append a Math.random function to a data-crystal attribute on an image. When the image is clicked, it will display the randomly assigned number to the HTML page and continue to add upon itself each time it is clicked.
Here is the code  code.

```
let currentScore = 0
let wins = 0
let losses = 0
let targetScore = 0


//function to assign number to crystals
$('#crystal1').append(`
data-crystal=${Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) }
`)

$('#crystal1').on('click', function (){
let crystalValue = $(this).attr('data-crystal')
crystalValue = parseInt(crystalValue)
crystalValue += currentScore
$('.scoreTotal').text(currentScore)
console.log(crystalValue)
})
```

Also, here is the related HTML.

```
<div class="row">
        <h4 class="scoreTotal"></h4>
    </div>    
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <img id="crystal1" src="./assets/images/crystal_1.png" alt="crystal 1">
        <img id="crystal2" src="./assets/images/crystal_2.png" alt="crystal 2">
        <img id="crystal3" src="./assets/images/crystal_3.png" alt="crystal 3">
        <img id="crystal4" src="./assets/images/crystal_4.png" alt="crystal 4">
    </div>
</div>
```

When I console.log crystalValue, I get NaN, even though when I look at the HTML in my dev tools, the data-crystal is being properly appended. I've tried everything I can to fix it, but can't seem to correct it. This my first post on Stack Overflow, I'm sorry if this is a common question or too simple.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: I had to edit real quick, it is there now

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to set `data-attributes` to with jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method, not jQuery's [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) method which inserts HTML at the end of an Element.

The documentation states that jQuery's `.data` method will:

> Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements or return the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.

```js
let currentScore = 0
let wins = 0
let losses = 0
let targetScore = 0


//function to assign number to crystals
$('#crystal1').data('crystal', Math.floor(Math.random() * 25));
console.log($('#crystal1').data('crystal'));
$('#crystal1').on('click', function (){
let crystalValue = $(this).data('crystal');
currentScore++;
crystalValue += currentScore;
$('.scoreTotal').text(crystalValue);
})
```

```css
html, body{
  padding: 10px;
}

img{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="row">
        <h4 class="scoreTotal"></h4>
    </div>    
    <div class="row">
        <img id="crystal1" src="./assets/images/crystal_1.png" alt="crystal 1">
        <img id="crystal2" src="./assets/images/crystal_2.png" alt="crystal 2">
        <img id="crystal3" src="./assets/images/crystal_3.png" alt="crystal 3">
        <img id="crystal4" src="./assets/images/crystal_4.png" alt="crystal 4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had the idea that I needed to use .data() but couldn't figure out how to implement it correctly, thank you for helping me.

Comment: @CortlandTaylor No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your not adding the data attribute correctly.
Using [jQuery's append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) is for inserting content into the end of each element on the set of the matched elements.

You should use [jQuery's data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
$('#crystal1').data('crystal', Math.floor(Math.random() * 25));
```

This will set the `data-crystal` attribute on all matched elements with the desired value.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svbyh46L/4/) with a working code.